Alternative to \p{Lo} Unicode Class in PostgreSQL Regex
I encountered a problem when working with regular expressions in PostgreSQL. It turns out that PostgreSQL has no support for the \p{Lo} class, which corresponds to the "Letter, Other" category in the Unicode standard. I need to use this class in my regular expression, but I can't find a way to do this in PostgreSQL.
I'm looking for an alternative approach or way to define this class through the available Unicode ranges in PostgreSQL. I would not want to manually list all possible characters as there are too many.
So far I've found a few Unicode ranges that partially fit:
[\u0370-\u03FF\u0400-\u04FF\u0590-\u05FF\u0600-\u06FF\u3040-\u30FF\u30FF\u4E00-\u9FFF].

However these ranges are not enough to fully cover \p{Lo}. Maybe there is a more comprehensive way to represent \p{Lo} in PostgreSQL or some known method that can help to achieve similar functionality?
Any help or links to specific Unicode ranges that could match \p{Lo} would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Yeah, it includes many more chars, both from the BMP and astral planes.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP "
Tip:  If you have pattern matching needs that go beyond this, consider writing a user-defined function in Perl or Tcl." A C++ extension is also an option.

I can provide all the Unicode ranges, but not sure it will work in PostgreSQL. Or are you writing in JS?

@WiktorStribiżew I’d appreciate the Unicode ranges, thanks! I need them specifically for postgresql regex.

You could create a function in perl to solve that straightforwardly:
create or replace function matchunicodeplo(char) 
returns bool as $$
    if ($_[0] =~ /\p{Lo}/g){    
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }   
$$ language plperl;

To check if perl language is installed in your database
select lanname 
from pg_language 
where lanname = 'plperl';

If not installed, then (maybe necessary to install the package postgresql-plperl-your_ver_number)
create extension plperl;

Then just run
select matchunicodeplo('あ');




matchunicodeplo




true




Any feedback on what is wrong?

@WiktorStribiżew Answer corrected according to your comments.

According to the Unicode tools, \p{Lo} can be replaced with
[\u00AA\u00BA\u01BB\u01C0-\u01C3\u0294\u05D0-\u05EA\u05EF-\u05F2\u0620-\u063F\u0641-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u0800-\u0815\u0840-\u0858\u0860-\u086A\u0870-\u0887\u0889-\u088E\u08A0-\u08C8\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0972-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u09FC\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AF9\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C5D\u0C60\u0C61\u0C80\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D04-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D56\u0D5F-\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E45\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E86-\u0E8A\u0E8C-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u1100-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u1711\u171F-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17DC\u1820-\u1842\u1844-\u1878\u1880-\u1884\u1887-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4C\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C77\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF3\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1CFA\u2135-\u2138\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u3006\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FF\u3105-\u312F\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BF\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\uA014\uA016-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4F7\uA500-\uA60B\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA66E\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA78F\uA7F7\uA7FB-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD\uA8FE\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E7-\uA9EF\uA9FA-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA6F\uAA71-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB\uAADC\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF66-\uFF6F\uFF71-\uFF9D\uFFA0-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC\U00010000-\U0001000B\U0001000D-\U00010026\U00010028-\U0001003A\U0001003C\U0001003D\U0001003F-\U0001004D\U00010050-\U0001005D\U00010080-\U000100FA\U00010280-\U0001029C\U000102A0-\U000102D0\U00010300-\U0001031F\U0001032D-\U00010340\U00010342-\U00010349\U00010350-\U00010375\U00010380-\U0001039D\U000103A0-\U000103C3\U000103C8-\U000103CF\U00010450-\U0001049D\U00010500-\U00010527\U00010530-\U00010563\U00010600-\U00010736\U00010740-\U00010755\U00010760-\U00010767\U00010800-\U00010805\U00010808\U0001080A-\U00010835\U00010837\U00010838\U0001083C\U0001083F-\U00010855\U00010860-\U00010876\U00010880-\U0001089E\U000108E0-\U000108F2\U000108F4\U000108F5\U00010900-\U00010915\U00010920-\U00010939\U00010980-\U000109B7\U000109BE\U000109BF\U00010A00\U00010A10-\U00010A13\U00010A15-\U00010A17\U00010A19-\U00010A35\U00010A60-\U00010A7C\U00010A80-\U00010A9C\U00010AC0-\U00010AC7\U00010AC9-\U00010AE4\U00010B00-\U00010B35\U00010B40-\U00010B55\U00010B60-\U00010B72\U00010B80-\U00010B91\U00010C00-\U00010C48\U00010D00-\U00010D23\U00010E80-\U00010EA9\U00010EB0\U00010EB1\U00010F00-\U00010F1C\U00010F27\U00010F30-\U00010F45\U00010F70-\U00010F81\U00010FB0-\U00010FC4\U00010FE0-\U00010FF6\U00011003-\U00011037\U00011071\U00011072\U00011075\U00011083-\U000110AF\U000110D0-\U000110E8\U00011103-\U00011126\U00011144\U00011147\U00011150-\U00011172\U00011176\U00011183-\U000111B2\U000111C1-\U000111C4\U000111DA\U000111DC\U00011200-\U00011211\U00011213-\U0001122B\U0001123F\U00011240\U00011280-\U00011286\U00011288\U0001128A-\U0001128D\U0001128F-\U0001129D\U0001129F-\U000112A8\U000112B0-\U000112DE\U00011305-\U0001130C\U0001130F\U00011310\U00011313-\U00011328\U0001132A-\U00011330\U00011332\U00011333\U00011335-\U00011339\U0001133D\U00011350\U0001135D-\U00011361\U00011400-\U00011434\U00011447-\U0001144A\U0001145F-\U00011461\U00011480-\U000114AF\U000114C4\U000114C5\U000114C7\U00011580-\U000115AE\U000115D8-\U000115DB\U00011600-\U0001162F\U00011644\U00011680-\U000116AA\U000116B8\U00011700-\U0001171A\U00011740-\U00011746\U00011800-\U0001182B\U000118FF-\U00011906\U00011909\U0001190C-\U00011913\U00011915\U00011916\U00011918-\U0001192F\U0001193F\U00011941\U000119A0-\U000119A7\U000119AA-\U000119D0\U000119E1\U000119E3\U00011A00\U00011A0B-\U00011A32\U00011A3A\U00011A50\U00011A5C-\U00011A89\U00011A9D\U00011AB0-\U00011AF8\U00011C00-\U00011C08\U00011C0A-\U00011C2E\U00011C40\U00011C72-\U00011C8F\U00011D00-\U00011D06\U00011D08\U00011D09\U00011D0B-\U00011D30\U00011D46\U00011D60-\U00011D65\U00011D67\U00011D68\U00011D6A-\U00011D89\U00011D98\U00011EE0-\U00011EF2\U00011F02\U00011F04-\U00011F10\U00011F12-\U00011F33\U00011FB0\U00012000-\U00012399\U00012480-\U00012543\U00012F90-\U00012FF0\U00013000-\U0001342F\U00013441-\U00013446\U00014400-\U00014646\U00016800-\U00016A38\U00016A40-\U00016A5E\U00016A70-\U00016ABE\U00016AD0-\U00016AED\U00016B00-\U00016B2F\U00016B63-\U00016B77\U00016B7D-\U00016B8F\U00016F00-\U00016F4A\U00016F50\U00017000-\U000187F7\U00018800-\U00018CD5\U00018D00-\U00018D08\U0001B000-\U0001B122\U0001B132\U0001B150-\U0001B152\U0001B155\U0001B164-\U0001B167\U0001B170-\U0001B2FB\U0001BC00-\U0001BC6A\U0001BC70-\U0001BC7C\U0001BC80-\U0001BC88\U0001BC90-\U0001BC99\U0001DF0A\U0001E100-\U0001E12C\U0001E14E\U0001E290-\U0001E2AD\U0001E2C0-\U0001E2EB\U0001E4D0-\U0001E4EA\U0001E7E0-\U0001E7E6\U0001E7E8-\U0001E7EB\U0001E7ED\U0001E7EE\U0001E7F0-\U0001E7FE\U0001E800-\U0001E8C4\U0001EE00-\U0001EE03\U0001EE05-\U0001EE1F\U0001EE21\U0001EE22\U0001EE24\U0001EE27\U0001EE29-\U0001EE32\U0001EE34-\U0001EE37\U0001EE39\U0001EE3B\U0001EE42\U0001EE47\U0001EE49\U0001EE4B\U0001EE4D-\U0001EE4F\U0001EE51\U0001EE52\U0001EE54\U0001EE57\U0001EE59\U0001EE5B\U0001EE5D\U0001EE5F\U0001EE61\U0001EE62\U0001EE64\U0001EE67-\U0001EE6A\U0001EE6C-\U0001EE72\U0001EE74-\U0001EE77\U0001EE79-\U0001EE7C\U0001EE7E\U0001EE80-\U0001EE89\U0001EE8B-\U0001EE9B\U0001EEA1-\U0001EEA3\U0001EEA5-\U0001EEA9\U0001EEAB-\U0001EEBB\U00020000-\U0002A6DF\U0002A700-\U0002B739\U0002B740-\U0002B81D\U0002B820-\U0002CEA1\U0002CEB0-\U0002EBE0\U0002EBF0-\U0002EE5D\U0002F800-\U0002FA1D\U00030000-\U0003134A\U00031350-\U000323AF]

Note you will need to transpile it in case your regex engine does not support \U000XXXXX notation.
